# MongoDB Aggregation: Return Different Result based on match case

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an **events** collection that has **time** field nested in all three levels [*events*, *events.results*, and *events.results.results*]

```
{   '_id': ObjectId('5b5a1a0e1667292602615a85'),
    events: [
            {   
                'results': [   
                               {   
                                   'name': 'some name A',
                                   'results': [   
                                                {   'text': 'some text A1',
                                                    'time': u'1532631565.28'},
                                                {   
                                                     'text': 'some text A2',
                                                     'time': u'1532631532.11'}    
                                              ]
                               },
                               {   
                                   'name': 'some name B',
                                   'results': [   
                                                {   'text': 'some text B1',
                                                    'time': u'1532631433.20'},
                                                {   
                                                     'text': 'some text B2',
                                                     'time': '1532631235.19'}    
                                              ]
                               }
                           ],
                'text': 'some title',
                'time': '1532631563.6'}
    ],
    'time': '1532631560.44'
}
```

I can find a match of certain event document by using the **$or** & **$match** the result from the three levels e.g

```
db.events.aggregate([{"$match":{"$or":[{"time":"1532631563.6"},{"events.time":"1532631563.6"},{"events.results.results.time":"1532631563.6"}]}}])
```

and this bring the whole document no matter on which level the time match.

What I want is to bring only the sub-document where the time matched, for example:

> if search for time: '1532631560.44'

**Result: the whole document since it match on top level**

```
{   '_id': ObjectId('5b5a1a0e1667292602615a85'),
            events: [
                    ...
                    ]}
```

> if search for times:'1532631563.6'

**Result: bring the second level sub-document **

```
{   
                'results': [   
                               {   
                                   'name': 'some name A',
                                   'results': [   
                                                {   'text': 'some text A1',
                                                    'ts': u'1532631565.28'},
                                                {   
                                                     'text': 'some text A2',
                                                     'ts': u'1532631532.11'}    
                                              ]
                               },
                               {   
                                   'name': 'some name B',
                                   'results': [   
                                                {   'text': 'some text B1',
                                                    'ts': u'1532631433.20'},
                                                {   
                                                     'text': 'some text B2',
                                                     'ts': '1532631235.19'}    
                                              ]
                               }
                           ],
                'title': 'some title',
                'time': '1532631563.6'}
```

> if search for time:'1532631235.19'

**Result: bring the lowest level sub-document**

```
{   
          'text': 'some text B2',
          'ts': '1532631235.19'}
```

***I am using MongoDB 3.4***

Thanks in advance!